# getting Undefined index: Biscuit error when using collection

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a collection of category wise products coming from database and for that purpose I am using collect() in laravel.

```php
$products = ConsumerProduct::where('status', 'Active')
            ->whereHas('masterStocks' , function ($query) use($warehouse) {
                 $query->where('master_stocks.warehouse_id', $warehouse->warehouse_id);
            })->with('masterStocks')
            ->with('category')
            ->join('product_categories', 'consumer_products.productCategory_id', '=', 'product_categories.category_id')
            ->orderBy('categoryName')
            ->get();

$categoryProducts = collect();

foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
 $categoryProducts[$product->category->categoryName][] = $product;
}
```

this is the result getting form db and it is fine.

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#604 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => App\ConsumerProduct {#622 ▼
      #primaryKey: "id"
      +timestamps: true
      #dates: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "consumer_products"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:32 [▶]
      #original: array:32 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▶]
      #touches: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    1 => App\ConsumerProduct {#623 ▶}
    2 => App\ConsumerProduct {#624 ▶}
    3 => App\ConsumerProduct {#625 ▶}
    4 => App\ConsumerProduct {#626 ▶}
  ]
}
```

In for loop i am getting error there is no index Biscuit. If i do like this:

```php
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
 $categoryProducts[$product->category->categoryName] = $product;
}
```

then it is giving me this result in which I am getting only one product of each category

```php
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#606 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "Biscuit" => App\ConsumerProduct {#622 ▶}
    "Pasta" => App\ConsumerProduct {#624 ▶}
    "Tea" => App\ConsumerProduct {#626 ▶}
  ]
}
```

how to resolve this and get the category wise products.

Comment: Show us what is in the `$products` array please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated my answer now check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your array :

```
$products = ConsumerProduct::where('status', 'Active')
            ->whereHas('masterStocks' , function ($query) use($warehouse) {
                $query->where('master_stocks.warehouse_id', $warehouse->warehouse_id);
            })->with('masterStocks')
            ->with('category')
            ->join('product_categories', 'consumer_products.productCategory_id', '=', 'product_categories.category_id')
            ->orderBy('categoryName')
            ->get();

$categoryProducts = [];
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    if (!isset($categoryProducts[$product->category->categoryName])) {
        $categoryProducts[$product->category->categoryName] = [];
    }
    $categoryProducts[$product->category->categoryName][] = $product;
}

$categoryProducts = collect($categoryProducts);
```

Comment: now I am getting this error
`Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect`

Comment: It may have a solution with only with `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, but I don't get it ... Somthing with `->keyBy('categoryName');`